# Mysql terminal instance is fine but MySQL Workbench not connecting to the database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I can connect to the mysql server from command line.
[Terminal Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay5Lu.png)

But I cannot connect from MySQL Workbench, I read similar questiones but I can't solve this problem.

I tried with starting as root or with sudo the MySQL Workbench
I created root user with password from terminal.
I tried convert localhost to 127.0.0.1 in MySQL Workbench

[MySQL Workbench Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHc7q.png)

[MySQL Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUOmx.png)

Comment: You say _I created root user with password from terminal_ How did you do that?

Comment: With mysql_secure_installation

Comment: So you set a password for `root` and now you have forgotten it?

Comment: I dont forget it.

Comment: Then use it when you login `mysql -uroot -p` and then enter the password.

Comment: Thanks, I can open mysql instance in terminal as you said but MySQL Workbench is not connecting its my problem

Comment: If I try the command mysql -u root -p without sudo I getting this error in terminal
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
But I can connect with sudo whatever password it is.

Comment: _But I can connect with sudo whatever password it is_ Of course that is an intended featuer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with this:

```
$ sudo mysql -u root # I had to use "sudo" since is new installation

mysql> USE mysql;
mysql> UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> exit;

$ sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: Are you connecting using workbench from the same machine that is running MySQL?